# Как обработать исключения? Telegram Bot aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, исключения, бот

у меня возникла трудность В общем, я написал Телеграм-бота на aiogram и задеплоил его на selectel.ru (serverless-окружение).

Проработала эта машина месяц, после чего начали сыпаться ошибки. Обратился в техподдержку. Мне сказали вот что:

"***Ошибка возникает из-за следующего исключения:
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: User not found
Вам следует проверить Ваш код на корректность и обработку указанного исключения, чтобы избежать аварийного завершения выполнения функции.***"

**Вопрос: как в данном случае обработать исключения во избежание АВАРИЙНОГО завершения программы?**

Код:

```
import logging
import os

from aiogram.types.chat_permissions import ChatPermissions
from time import time
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

# log
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)





bot = Bot(os.environ.get("TOKEN"))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)




# handlers



async def filter_text_messages(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id == -1000000000000 or message.chat.id == -1000000000000:
        if message.from_user.id != 510880000:
            if "" in message.text:
                await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_polls=False, can_send_other_messages=False), until_date=int(time() + 10800))
                await message.delete()
                await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio = "https://t.me/link")

async def filter_photo_messages(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id == -1000000000000 or message.chat.id == -1000001310030:
        if message.from_user.id != 000000000:
            if message.caption:
                await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_polls=False, can_send_other_messages=False), until_date=int(time() + 10800))
                await message.delete()
                await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio = "https://t.me/link")

async def filter_video_messages(message: types.Message):    
    if message.chat.id == -1000000000000 or message.chat.id == -1000000000000:
        if message.from_user.id != 500001762:
            if message.caption:
                await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_polls=False, can_send_other_messages=False), until_date=int(time() + 10800))
                await message.delete()
                await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio = "https://t.me/link")

async def filter_audio_messages(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id == -1000000000000 or message.chat.id == -1000000000000:
        if message.from_user.id != 000000000:
            if message.caption:
                await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_polls=False, can_send_other_messages=False), until_date=int(time() + 10800))
                await message.delete()
                await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio = "https://t.me/link")

async def filter_document_messages(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id == -1000000000000 or message.chat.id == -1000000000000:
        if message.from_user.id != 000001762:
            if message.caption:
                await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_polls=False, can_send_other_messages=False), until_date=int(time() + 10800))
                await message.delete()
                await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio = "https://t.me/link")

# Selectel Lambda funcs
async def register_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(filter_text_messages, content_types=['text'])
    dp.register_message_handler(filter_photo_messages, content_types=['photo'])
    dp.register_message_handler(filter_video_messages, content_types=['video'])
    dp.register_message_handler(filter_audio_messages, content_types=['audio'])
    dp.register_message_handler(filter_document_messages, content_types=['document'])


async def process_event(update, dp: Dispatcher):
    Bot.set_current(dp.bot)
    await dp.process_update(update)

# Selectel serverless entry point
async def main(**kwargs):
    await register_handlers(dp)
    update = types.Update.to_object(kwargs)
    await process_event(update, dp)
    return 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну сделайте простую конструкцию `try` - `except`, делов-то...

```
try:
    #ваш код
except:
    #обработка исключения
```

Comment: Помог ответ? Поставьте галочку ;)

Comment: Хорошо. Вот еще вопрос: что я должен написать после except?

Comment: Ну, то, что вы хотите сделать. Например, `time.sleep(1)` (не забудьте импортировать модуль `time` ;) )